# an uxepected output with dynamic arrays in a struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct

so my problem is when i allocate a memory from a string in a one of the members of the array gets corrupted and i have no idea why is that.
my main is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define maxsize 512
#define charsize 100
typedef struct Books {
   char* id;
   char* title;
   char* author;
   char* pages;
   char* year;
   char* subject;
} book;
char* filename;
int libsize=4;
int bookcount=1;
void printbooks(book books[]);
void printbooksf(book books[]);
void srchbook(book books[]);
void delbook(book books[]);
void pick(book books[]);
void addbook(book books[]);
void addbookf(book books[]);
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 if (argc < 1)
    return -1;
 filename=argv[1];
 FILE* fptr;
 char tempstring[maxsize],* token;
 int i=0,ch;
book *books=NULL;
fptr=fopen(filename,"r");
if(fptr==NULL)
return-1;
//this count how many books are in the file
  while(ch!= EOF){
    ch=fgetc(fptr);
    if(ch == '\n')
    ++bookcount;
  }
 fclose(fptr);
 while(libsize<bookcount){
    libsize *= 1.5;
 }
 books = (book*) malloc(libsize*sizeof(book));
 if(books==NULL)
    exit(-1);
    //starting size for the pointer
    for(i=0;i<bookcount;i++){
    books[i].id=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    books[i].title=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    books[i].author=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    books[i].pages=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    books[i].year=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    books[i].subject=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    }
 fptr=fopen(filename,"r");
 if(fptr==NULL)
    return-1;
//this gets all the books into the book array
  for(i=0;i<bookcount;i++){
    fgets(tempstring,maxsize,fptr);
    token=strtok(tempstring,",");
    strcpy(books[i].id,token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(books[i].title,token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(books[i].author,token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(books[i].pages,token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(books[i].year,token);
    token=strtok(NULL,",");
    strcpy(books[i].subject,token);
   }
 fclose(fptr);
 printf("to add a book press 1\n");
 printf("to delete a book press 2\n");
 printf("to find a book press 3\n");
 printf("to print all books press 4\n");
 printf("to save library in a file press 5\n");
 printf("to add books from a file press 6\n");
 printf("to exit press 0\n");
 pick(books);
    return 1;
}
```

now the output i get from printbooks is

```
Treasure Island
Heir to The Empire
Plumbing for Dummies
Berserk(!!!!)
The Troll Cookbook : Human Delights
Funny Cats
Linus the Vegetarian T. rex
Algebra 3
The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy
```

how ever when i use addbook and then printbook one of the members gets corrupted so i get

```
Treasure Island
x-
Plumbing for Dummies
Berserk(!!!!)
The Troll Cookbook : Human Delights
Funny Cats
Linus the Vegetarian T. rex
Algebra 3
The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy
the book i added
```

addbook is

```
void addbook(book books[]){
    char tempstring[maxsize];
    char bugfixer;//gets the /n instead of  the temp string
    bugfixer=getc(stdin);
    int i;
    ++bookcount;
    if(libsize<bookcount){
    while(libsize < bookcount){
    libsize*=1.5;}
    books=realloc(books,libsize);
    }
    if(books==NULL){
        printf("not enough space\n");
        exit(-1);}
    for(i=bookcount-1;i<bookcount;i++){
    books[i].id=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    books[i].title=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    books[i].author=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    books[i].pages=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    books[i].year=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    books[i].subject=(char*)malloc(charsize);
    }
    for(i=bookcount-1;i<bookcount;++i){
        printf("add the id\n");
        gets(tempstring);
        strcpy(books[i].id,tempstring);
        printf("add the title\n");
        gets(tempstring);
        strcpy(books[i].year,tempstring);
        printf("add the author\n");
        gets(tempstring);
        strcpy(books[i].title,tempstring);
        printf("add the pages\n");
        gets(tempstring);
        strcpy(books[i].pages,tempstring);
        printf("add the year\n");
        gets(tempstring);
        strcpy(books[i].author,tempstring);
        printf("add the subject\n");
        gets(tempstring);
        strcpy(books[i].subject,tempstring);
    }
    printf("book number %d added",bookcount);
    printf("\n");
    pick(books);
}
`
```

and printbook is

```
void printbooks(book books[]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<bookcount;i++){
    printf("%s\n",books[i].title);
    }
    printf("\n");
    pick(books);
}
```

now what im trying to understand here is why only the 2nd member gets corrupted
and why should any member gets corrupted

Comment: Stop using `gets` which was deprecated and now obsolete.

Comment: `if (argc < 1)` --> `if (argc < 2)`

Comment: I do not understand why you `malloc` a fixed amount of memory to every `char*` pointer in the `struct`, instead of defining each of those members to be an array. The reason to use a `char*` member, is to allocate the *actual* memory needed, perhaps with `strdup`.

Comment: its a setup for getting every input correct if i set a fixed amout it can still crash i plan on using strln() as an idicator to how much to length should be.

Comment: `while(ch!= EOF){` using uninitialized variable at first time.

Comment: From BLUEPIXY the idiomatic way is `while((ch = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF) { if(ch == '\n') ++bookcount; }`

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be other issues as pointed out in the comments.
But as you refer to behaviour when calling `addbook`, this behaviour has to do with freeing memory:

Within `addbook(book books[])`, you `realloc` parameter `books` (i.e. `books=realloc(books,libsize)`. Thereby, the memory to which parameter `books` points to is most likely freed, and a new memory location is assigned. Note, however, that a variable passed to function `addbook` will still point to the "old" and in the meanwhile freed memory.

If you `realloc` a parameter, then the parameter should be a pointer to a pointer, i.e. `book **book`, such that the code calling function `addbook` will get a pointer to the new memory block as well. Code in `addbook` has to be changed accordingly.

Comment: i tried to do what you said and it seems that the problem still occur i did something liek 
    book** bookptr;
    bookptr=&books;
...
bookptr=realloc(books,libsize);
....
pick(bookptr);